# Unexpected table created by ddl-auto update

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have spring-boot application with this two JPA entities joined by one-to-many relation.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "todos")
public class ToDo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @Column
    private LocalDate targetDate;

    public ToDo() {
    }

    // Constructors, getters, setter, etc.
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<ToDo> toDos = new ArrayList<>();

    // Constructors, getters, setter, etc.
}
```

For such kind of relation I expect to have only two tables but Hibernate create three.

```
Hibernate: create table todos (id  bigserial not null, description varchar(255), target_date date, user_id int8, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table users (id  bigserial not null, password varchar(255) not null, username varchar(255) not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table users_to_dos (user_id int8 not null, to_dos_id int8 not null)
```

The last one look useless. Why it created and could I prevent that? May be something is wrong in code?

Answer (score 1):

Since your toDos list on the user entity does not have a `@JoinColumn` annotation, hibernate assumes there's an additional mapping table for this and creates it.

Add the `@JoinColumn` annotation to the field and it will not be created

See more on [this guide](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-unidirectional-one-to-many-association-without-junction-table/)

Comment: That's mean I have @JoinColumn annotation in wrong place? It should be on the list field?

Comment: where do you want to hold the join column? on the `users` or the `todos` table? to me it seems bad to have it twice, so the join column (along with the field) should be only on one of them. but generally speaking, if you have `@OneToMany` without `@JoinColumn`, that implies a separate join table

Comment: One user could have several todos connected todos it. Also wired thing about configuration in question that Hibernate already create join field `user_id` and use it but also creates junction table which is empty all the time. Strange...

Comment: it creates it since there's a field with `@OneToMany` on the user entity, the fact that there's a reversed relation on the other entity doesn't matter. Sounds to me that you don't need the todos field on the user entity, the relation is stored on the `Todo entity`. If you want to save it on both tables, add the `@JoinColumn` to the field

Comment: How I understand mappedBy on collection side and `@JoinColumn` on another side is the most correct. Is that true?

Answer (score 0):

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy="speciality",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)     
@JsonIgnore      
private Set<DepartmentMaster> departmentSpeciality;
```

```java
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)   
@JoinColumn(name="SPECALITY_ID")    
@JsonIgnore     
private SpecialityMaster speciality;
```

Try to do the mapping like this I don't think it should create any problem.